# How do I make band names appear on iTunes/Music?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

On the right are songs I've purchased on iTunes itself, and on the left are songs I've bought (yes, I paid for them/supported the bands) from other sources, namely their websites and a code from a tour.

How do I make the bands' names appear (Undercast and Sick Puppies, respectively) below the album names as they do on the right?

Thanks!

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

Select the songs in iTunes, then Get Info (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) and add the name of the band to the Artist field.

If you want different tracks to be by different artists, you can unify the album under a single artist using the Album Artist tag.

[image]

Comment: Alas I did try that but it didn't work. Thank you for getting the ball rolling, though - and although the answer you posted has doubtlessly been posted before, thanks for not marking this as a duplicate question.

When we do your technique (as was my first attempt), it does work fine for iTunes, but not the music app on the iPhone.

It turns out I have to edit the information on Get Info in my PC's iTunes Library, then add it to my phone's music (I was trying to change Get Info on the file on the phone). 

Thank you for your help, though :)